# Cannot Register to Parse Server Back4App

Tags: java, android, parse-server, firebase-remote-config, back4app

I have an Android app and trying to register new account for user , I am using Back4app as backend for my application and when I try to register new account it gives me error that account could not be created.

here is my register method:

```
public void registerNow(){

    if (QuickHelp.isInternetAvailable(Application.getInstance().getApplicationContext())){

        String password = passwordField.getText().toString().trim();

        String email = emailField.getText().toString().replaceAll(" ", "").trim();

        String name = nameField.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.length() == 0 && !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {

            emailField.setError(getString(R.string.com_parse_ui_no_email_toast));
        } else if (name.length() == 0 && config.isParseSignupNameFieldEnabled()) {

            nameField.setError(getString(R.string.com_parse_ui_no_name_toast));

        } else if (dateCheck == null) {

            mBirthday.setError(getString(R.string.signup_user_date));

        } else if (password.length() == 0) {

            passwordField.setError(getString(R.string.com_parse_ui_no_password_toast));
        } else if (password.length() < minPasswordLength) {

            passwordField.setError(getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.com_parse_ui_password_too_short_toast, minPasswordLength, minPasswordLength));

        } else if (gender == null){

            showToast(getString(R.string.gender_missing));
        } else {


            String[] parts = name.split(" ");

            String firstName = parts[0];

            String username = (name+firstName).toLowerCase().trim().replaceAll(" ", "");

            User user = ParseObject.create(User.class);

            user.setUid(QuickHelp.generateUId());
            user.setColBirthdate(birthday);
            user.setAge(ageInt);
            user.setColFirstName(firstName);
            user.setColFullName(name);
            user.setUsername(username);
            user.setPassword(password);
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setColGender(gender);
            user.setPopularity(0);
            user.setPrefMinAge(Config.MinimumAgeToRegister);
            user.setPrefMaxAge(Config.MaximumAgeToRegister);
            user.setPrefLocationIsNearBy(true);
            user.addCredit(Config.WelcomeCredit);
            user.setBio(Config.bio);
            user.setPasswordEnabled(true);

            loadingStart();
            user.signUpInBackground(e -> {
                if (isActivityDestroyed()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (e == null) {
                    loadingFinish();
                    signupSuccessFbLink();

                } else {
                    loadingFinish();
                    debugLog(getString(R.string.com_parse_ui_login_warning_parse_signup_failed) +
                            e.toString());
                    switch (e.getCode()) {
                        case ParseException.INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS:
                            showToast(R.string.com_parse_ui_invalid_email_toast);
                            emailField.setError(getString(R.string.com_parse_ui_invalid_email_toast));
                            break;
                        case ParseException.USERNAME_TAKEN:
                            showToast(R.string.com_parse_ui_username_taken_toast);
                            nameField.setError(getString(R.string.com_parse_ui_username_taken_toast));
                            break;
                        case ParseException.EMAIL_TAKEN:
                            showToast(R.string.com_parse_ui_email_taken_toast);
                            emailField.setError(getString(R.string.com_parse_ui_invalid_email_toast));
                            break;
                        default:
                            showToast(R.string.com_parse_ui_signup_failed_unknown_toast);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    } else {

        QuickHelp.noInternetConnect(getActivity());
    }

}
```

and here is my Parse server settings :

```
 // Parse Server
public static final String SERVER_URL = "https://parseapi.back4app.com/";
public static final String LIVE_QUERY_URL = "ws://chattyapp.back4app.io/";
static final String SERVER_API_KEY = "2krCGWymXGp9jLsqDuBEFORQn6wAj65TRptlniCj";
static final String SERVER_CLIENT_KEY = "4GeQcUOmljC6WPKgjRcSn67UH6CytLCsJqp5yV1J";
```

and this is what console gives me when I press create account:

D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf59885f0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc3946bd0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf59885f0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc3946bd0)
I/chatty: uid=10151(com.angopapo.datoo) RenderThread identical 3 lines
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf59885f0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc3946bd0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf59885f0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc3946bd0)
I/chatty: uid=10151(com.angopapo.datoo) RenderThread identical 12 lines
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf59885f0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc3946bd0)
W/.angopapo.dato: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V (blacklist,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setHostname(Ljava/lang/String;)V (blacklist,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
W/.angopapo.dato: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'FirebaseRemoteConfigValue' exists for parameter key 'fpr_session_max_duration_min'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'FirebaseRemoteConfigValue' exists for parameter key 'fpr_enabled'.
No value of type 'FirebaseRemoteConfigValue' exists for parameter key 'fpr_disabled_android_versions'.
W/.angopapo.dato: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'FirebaseRemoteConfigValue' exists for parameter key 'fpr_enabled'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'FirebaseRemoteConfigValue' exists for parameter key 'fpr_disabled_android_versions'.
No value of type 'FirebaseRemoteConfigValue' exists for parameter key 'fpr_vc_network_request_sampling_rate'.
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf59885f0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc3946bd0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf59885f0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc3946bd0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf59885f0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc3946bd0)

Comment: Hi Alex! Your app credentials are the most important keys as they give you access to your app, what I would like to recommend is that you remove the Parse server settings here and open a ticket on the Back4App website and the support team will help you :)

Comment: @nataliec I think it is going to be the only solution now